# Symfony2 Firewall: protect /web folder

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am developping a SF2 web-app which is fully behind a firewall: nobody shouldn't be able to see or modify anything before behing logged (except login form, of course).

So here is the `firewall` part of my `security.yml` file:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main_login:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: true
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      false
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            path:       fos_user_security_logout
            target:     /
```

This works fine: if I type the url `http://mywebsite.com/app.php/article/show/1` while unlogged, I am forwarded to the login page.

**My problem is** that I have some documents and media files located in Symfony's `web` directory (e.g. `myapp/web/document/myTextFile.txt`). They are accessible via my app for logged users, but also for **non-logged users**!

Anybody who types `http://mywebsite.com/app.php/document/myTextFile.txt` can download the file...

Why doesn't the `pattern: ^/` line prevent this? Is the `web` folder excluded by default because it contains `app.php` and `js/`and `css/` folder?

How do I protect my documents?

---

**Update: Display protected images**

I tried the solution suggested by Gerry, it works fine to protect the download of my documents.

However, I also have pictures in my `document` folder and I would like to display these pictures, directly included in the relevant pages.

For example, in `http://mywebsite.com/app.php/article/show/1` there will be some text and the picture `myapp/app/Resources/document/AAA.jpg`, and in `http://mywebsite.com/app.php/article/show/2` there will be some text and the picture `myapp/app/Resources/document/BBB.jpg`, etc.

I tried to do it with Assetic but it seems that it is done for "static" images (like top logo, or images which are not object-dependent).

A solution I see is to convert the image in Base64 and include it like this : `<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64(...)" />`, but it seems really ugly...

Comment: I think this Stackoverflow topic might help you 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148272/assetic-files-in-symfony-are-behind-the-firewall][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148272/assetic-files-in-symfony-are-behind-the-firewall

Comment: Why don't you upload your images directly into `src/My/MyBundle/Resources/public`?

Comment: What should I put in my image's `src` (`<img src="?????" />`) then? Because if I put `<img src="{{ asset('../app/Resources/documents/'~document.fileName)}}"/>` and then `app/console assetic:dump` or `app/console assets:install`, the content of `app/Resources/documents` folder will be copied (or symlinked) back to `web/`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web directory is your public root directory, being served by the webserver (Apache/Nginx/...).

By default any request to an existing file does not pass Symfony at all, so no firewall setting is going to prevent access to files residing in the web root.

The clean solution is to move these files to another directory, outside the webroot, for example `app/Resources/uploads`. Then you could write a Symfony controller for downloading these files.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit: I detailled some of my needs.

Comment: It works exactly the same for any kind of file, also images. Just make sure to set the correct Content-Type header when serving them from your controller.

Comment: To download them, ok, I tried and it works for images as well as any other doc. But how to display them *inside* a page?

Comment: Displaying images in HTML is essentially asking the browser to download and render them... There is no difference at the serving side. Just use the URL as the src attribute of the image.

Comment: Hum! I tried many things but not that. For me, the src attribute was expecting an URL like `http://server.com/folder/image.jpg`, and as my controller gives a "Response", I didn't think it would match. Anyway, thanks for the solution which is as clean as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working installation of Symfony right now, but try to move your documents from web, if will firewall proceed.

Let me know the answer please, will try to find out a solution if it will not work, or if you will not be able to move those files in production.

Comment: Where should I move them? In `app/`? How do I access them if they are here? FYI, I use [the method described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) to upload my files

Comment: Oh, I forgot the structure of Symfony.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about any solution yet, maybe htaccess?